# Firestore 'arrayContains' does not work in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch the data from firestore. So, I created function to get data as follows. It works with 'isEqualTo' but does not fetch when I change the where clause to 'arrayContains'.

```
Query<Map<String, dynamic>> detailCollection =
        _firestore.collectionGroup(collectionName);
return detailCollection
                  .where('title', arrayContains: 'cb1')
                    .snapshots();
```

my fiestore rule is as follows,

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to get the data from 'posts' collection.
[image]

[image]
Appreciate if anyone can show me, what is the cause of the issue?

Comment: I don't see here that you have a document in a posts collection with a field called title that's an array that contains the value "cb1".  If no such document exists, then your query will return nothing.

Comment: Can you show any document with arrays data in it or add the console error results.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, I added attachment related to 'cb1', actually, it fetches 'cb1' when I use 'isequalTo' insteaad of 'arrayContains'

Comment: @FransiTsena, there is no error thrown by the above function.

Comment: Ok then make sure one of the documents has a an array with a title of "title" and value of "cb1" maybe the query is returning null

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do will not work.  array-contains queries only work with fields that are actually arrays.  Your cb1 field is just a string.  It's not an array, so it would never match an array-contains filter.

If you want to use array-contains, then you will need to use an array type field.  You might want to review the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership), which pretty clearly states that the field must be an array.

Comment: Hi @Doug, Even though I changed to 'where('title', arrayContains: ['cb1','cb2'])' it did not work.

Comment: I referred this example : https://pretagteam.com/question/firestore-search-query-flutter

Comment: Please read my answer again.  The field you are filtering on is not an array, so you can't use array-contains on it.  It just won't work.  You can only use array-contains with an array type field.  No other data type will match.  If you are trying to find documents where a field value could be any one of several different values, you should use an "in" filter instead.

Comment: Thanks @Doug, it works with 'whereIn'